# How to set a Video as a background for half the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was wondering if you can set up a video background as half of the screen for a home page.

I'm currently using Bootstrap 4's grid system to separate the page and html5 to set the video.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="leftcontainer" class="col-md-6">
            <div id="video">
                <video class"video-fluid z-depth-1" autoplay loop muted width="100%">
                    <source src="videos/backgroundVid2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                </video> 
                <button>Download Brochure</button>
                <button>Contact Us</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when I run the code, I get a video that does not properly fit into the container and is not responsive to the screen changing sizes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please **edit** your question and show your CSS  and generate a working example. Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t6fcdsu9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't really read out what exactly you want, but this one is a working fiddle concerning the responsiveness using a youtube video (which isn't being displayed, I assume it's being blocked):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HTEX0qaSY3U" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <button>Download Brochure</button>
            <button>Contact Us</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In case this isn't what you wanted, please amplify your question.

You might also achieve the same effect by solely replacing `iframe` with you video tag - couldn't test it though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do in this way...

If you provide us CSS as well as Javascript then we will help you more...

Source : [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp)

```js
// Get the video
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");

// Get the button
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Pause and play the video, and change the button text
function myFunction() {
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
    btn.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    video.pause();
    btn.innerHTML = "Play";
  }
}
```

```css
/* Style the video: 100% width and height to cover the entire window */

#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}


/* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */

.content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* Style the button used to pause/play the video */

#myBtn {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!-- The video -->
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://ak8.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/16923118/preview/stock-footage-rain-and-light-on-window-of-moving-vehicle-modern-travel-concept.webm" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<!-- Optional: some overlay text to describe the video -->
<div class="content">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <!-- Use a button to pause/play the video with JavaScript -->
  <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Pause</button>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you...